# Reducing Flea3 image size without changing FoV

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently acquired a Flea3, but the full-size 2080 x 1552 image has rather an overhead on my system. Is there a way to set the camera to keep the same wide field of view but reduce the resolution, so it passes, say, a 1040 x 776 image to ROS? I of course know I can set an ROI, but that reduces the FoV, which I wish to avoid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245453/reducing-flea3-image-size-without-changing-fov/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2016-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use 2x2 binning or subsampling to accomplish that resolution reduction, according to Section 9.2 'Video Modes Overview' in http://www.ptgrey.com/support/downloads/10120/

This ros node looks to support it https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/blob/0bcd3c54320f7265069686801f441a3592e7f4c7/pointgrey_camera_driver/src/nodelet.cpp#L107, also this alternative with `SetGigEImageBinningSettings` https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flea3/blob/8c0d1ae7fef3d1544dd285869fac5711bdd0421e/flycapture/include/flycapture/GigECamera.h#L268

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2016-10-11**:
I see. That is exactly the information that I was looking for; I have a FL3-U3-32S2C, so the binning will also allow me to run at 60 fps.